# Python3 appending key value pair alters previous entry

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to build the following JSON:

```
{'Keys-1': [{'Key1': 'Value1'}, {'Key1': 'Value2'}]}
```

Here is the code I am using to build this JSON:

```
existingFile = {}
importobjs = []
importobj = {}
objkey = 'Key1'
objvalue = 'Value1'
importobj[objkey] = objvalue
importobjs.append(importobj)
objvalue = 'Value2'
importobj[objkey] = objvalue
importobjs.append(importobj)
existingFile['Keys-1'] = importobjs
```

Works almost perfectly, except the value of the first key-value pair is updated to 'Value2'

```
{'Keys-1': [{'Key1': 'Value2'}, {'Key1': 'Value2'}]}
```

Comment: Well you add **the same object** twice to the list...

Comment: append method use reference of the object, if you change one more time the object importobj, then append it, you will see 3 times the same pair of values.

Comment: This is the result of "pass by reference vs pass by value" if you need better google search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code (as mentioned in the comments) is that the objects are being passed by reference instead of by value. What your `existingFile` actually looks like is

```
{'Keys-1': [object@importobj_address, object@importobj_address]}
```

So your array contains two of the exact same objects. If you change `importobj` again and add it to `importobjs`, then you will have 3 of the exact same objects in the array.

Here is an example of how you can implement this correctly:

```
existingFile = {}
importobjs = []
first_key = 'Key1'
importobjs.append({first_key:'Value1'})
importobjs.append({first_key:'Value2'})
existingFile['Keys-1'] = importobjs
```

To expand the example:

```
existingFile = {}
first_objs = []
first_key = 'Key1'
first_objs.append({first_key:'Value1'})
first_objs.append({first_key:'Value2'})
existingFile['Keys-1'] = first_objs
second_objs = []
second_key = 'Key2'
second_objs.append({second_key:'Value3'})
second_objs.append({second_key:'Value4'})
existingFile['Keys-2'] = second_objs
```

However, much of these issues would be avoided by looping through lists rather than variables for each string.

Comment: Thank you Hayley Guillou, 
I actually do have two loops in the real code, I was just breaking this down so I could easily understand what was happening.
The single difference to me here seems that if the variable importobj is equal to the value {'Key1': 'Value2'} and I do the importobjs.append(importobj) command, that will overwrite the first pair.
but your method adds the key-value pair as {key:'value'} and not as a string that contains the value "{'key1':'value'}".
Your method works well! So Thank you again!